# Downloading file as a result of POST request (IdHTTP)

Tags: c++builder

I know there's IdHTTP->Get to download data to filestream.
But I need to do that after post request

```
TFileStream* fs = new TFileStream(fileName, fmCreate|fmOpenWrite);

TStringList * S=new TStringList();
S->Clear();
S->Add("info=" + kindainfo);
fs = IdHTTP1->Post(URL, S);
```

That's what I need to get.. because I don't think file will be fine with AnsiString

Comment: `AnsiString` has nothing to do with your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found answer

> IdHTTP1->Post(URL, S, fs);